# SOQL count number of grouped rows

Tags: soql, group-by

Here's the gist of my query:

```
Select count(Id) from OBJECT where (yada yada) GROUP By Field1, Field2
```

It's returning 43 rows of Count(Id).  Instead, I need it to return 43.  I've seen others answer this type of question who are working in Apex, but in my case I'm building a query for use in a Conga Composer button.  So I need the query to be constructed to simply return 43, without any "help" from code.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you get a single number when you're grouping by fields?  what are you expecting to receive for each grouping?

Comment: I'm not interested in returning the counts of records per group, only in the number of groups that the query produces, in this case 43.  I looked into using GROUP BY ROLLUP but I don't think that will get me what I need.

Comment: So you want to know how many groupings there are, not how many records in each grouping?

Comment: Nick, yes that's correct.  Thanks for any tips you may have.

Comment: Just clarifying: I built a query with the developer console that yields 43 rows of count(Id), showing the counts per row.  I don't need the counts per row.  I just want the query to return a single number: 43. I keep thinking I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Has anyone else out there had this same requirement -- to return the number of grouped rows?  How did you construct your query?  Thanks again for any tips.